# Selenium webdriver: How can I click these links?

Tags: java, javascript, automation, hyperlink, selenium-webdriver

```
<a onclick="requestReportGeneration('857f23e1baa767622a91f970963d8918', 'reportDiv31','CSV')" href="javascript:void[0];">CSV</a>
<a onclick="requestReportGeneration('64107e36323e5877c986edc98a17b6e8', 'reportDiv32','CSV')" href="javascript:void[0];">CSV</a>
<a onclick="requestReportGeneration('2cad4d4e5c8855c47a88b6ddf8345735', 'reportDiv33','CSV')" href="javascript:void[0];">CSV</a>
```

I have these three links on a page and I want to click each one in turn. I am reading all the links on the page into a list of WebElements and then I go through each one in turn if the href contains javascript:void[0] I then try to click it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < allLinks.size(); i++) {
    String reportLink = allLinks.get(i).getAttribute("href");

    if (reportLink.contains("javascript:void[0];")) 
    {
        allLinks.get(i).click();
        /// Do some more stuff
    }
```

The problem is I keep getting an error saying the element is not visible. I have also tried just loading the page and instead of getting all the links doing

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,\"javascript:void[0]\")]")).click();
```

but that also just gives element not visible error.
Can anybody tell me why this isn't working?

Comment: Please inspect that link and you should be able to see a attribute called `style` with the value `display:none` which makes the element not accessible to WebDriver.

Comment: I can't see that. I have inspected the element and the css for it is: `table tr td a {
    text-decoration: underline;
        -moz-text-blink: none;
        -moz-text-decoration-color: -moz-use-text-color;
        -moz-text-decoration-line: underline;
        -moz-text-decoration-style: solid;`  Also if I use firebug I can update the css to have display:none and then I don't see the links at all.   I can see the links on the page I am just having trouble getting webdriver to click them.

Comment: Is the xPath right? You can inspect the element on chrome, right click on that DOM element and copy the xPath

Comment: I have just commented all the other code out. The xpath is correct and the test doesn't fail but it isn't clicking the link.

Comment: Are the links contained in a span at all? Some javascript packages that create elements on a page for you will do their own formatting and at times you must click on the parent element to interact with them when using Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a breakpoint before the while loop, debug your script, then step into it and use Eclipse's Display tab to interrogate what is up with the links. Try evaluating sample statements like:

```
allLinks.size();
allLinks.get(i).isDisplayed();
allLinks.get(i).isEnabled();
```

There must be something odd about the links (or the way webdriver is seeing them), but debugging like this will let you find out what it is.